# Вывод значений в определённых столбцах таблицы

Tags: php

Необходимо построить на основании двух таблиц SQL одну общую таблицу Ведомость. Первая задаёт количество и названия столбцов с дисциплинами. Вторая хранит данные об учениках и их оценках. Каждая запись об оценке по дисциплине уникальна. Проблема состоит в выводе записей второй таблицы в необходимом формате, так, чтобы в дисциплинах, по которым поставлена оценка выводилось значение оценки, а по которым не поставлена – ничего.

Для наглядности
[image: Ведомость]

Подскажите как организовать вывод так, чтобы на данных позициях вместо Array выводилось значения $columns[$i][$j]['record_id'] и $columns[$i][$j]['record_mark']?

Код:

```
    for ($i=0; $i < $studentsLength; $i++) {   
                    $columns[$i] = [];
                    for ($k=0; $k < $recordsLength; $k++) {                                                         
                        for ($j=0; $j < $disciplinesLength; $j++) { 
                            if ($records[$k]->Discipline_ID == $disciplines[$j]->id && $records[$k]->Student == $students[$i]->StudentName) {                                    
                                $columns[$i][$j]['record_id'] = $records[$k]->id;
                                $columns[$i][$j]['record_mark'] = $records[$k]->Mark;
                            }
                        }
                    }                        
                    print "<tr>
                            <td>{$students[$i]->StudentName}</td>";
                            for ($l=0; $l < $disciplinesLength; $l++) {                                     
                                //print_r($columns[$i]);
                                if (in_array($l, $columns[$i])) {
                                   print "<td>{$columns[$i][$l]}</td>";
                                } else {
                                    print "<td></td>";
                                }

                            }
                    print "</tr>";
```

Comment: А причем тут sql. в коде только работа с массивами php, к БД никакого отношения не имеющая

Comment: И раз там надпись array, значит наверное предполагается, что значений может быть несколько. Если же там одно значение, то надо просто знать в каком элементе массива оно лежит и выводить этот конкретный элемент

Comment: @Mike да, в ячейке столбца должны храниться id и оценки. Но что бы я ни делал, у меня не получается не то, что вывести, банально положить в $columns[$i][$j] необходимые значения.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается проверкой на существование значения в необходимом столбце с помощью функции isset() в последнем цикле.

```
for ($l=0; $l < $disciplinesLength; $l++) {      
                                if (isset($columns[$i][$l])) {
                                    print "<td>{$columns[$i][$l]['record_id']}{$columns[$i][$l]['record_mark']}</td>";
                                } else {
                                    print "<td></td>";
                                }
                            }
```